# Finding vector orthogonal to two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

How can one find a vector orthogonal to two vectors when the metric is not the Euclidean one, i.e.
\begin{align}
\notag
G=
\begin{pmatrix}
k&l&0&0\\
l&k&0&0\\
0&0&l&s\\
0&0&s&l
\end{pmatrix} \;\; ,
\end{align}
where $k$,$l$,$s$ are some functions.
Thank you!

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question unless you tell us what kind of metric you **do** mean.

Comment: @Lee I wrote a metric, thank you!

Comment: @NovakDjokovic A metric is, by definition, a function mapping a pair of objects into the real numbers. What you wrote is not a metric.

Comment: @5xum Can you tell me why it is not a metric.

Comment: @NovakDjokovic Because it is not a function from $X\times X$ to $\mathbb R$, which is the definition of a metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ (equipped with the euclidean metric), we know you can use the cross-product. However, even *with the euclidean metric*, we don't have this tool for $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\not=3$). Outside of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can generally turn to either brute force or Gram-Schmidt.

Note: Your question said "metric", but you really need an "inner product". Otherwise, what do you mean by "orthogonal"?

Suppose you have $v,w \in V$ where $V$ is an inner product space (with inner product $\langle \cdot\;,\;\cdot \rangle$).

Let $u$ be any vector in $V$ such that $u \not\in \mathrm{span} \{v,w\}$.

Then run [Gram–Schmidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process):

> $v' = v$
>
> $w' = w-\dfrac{\langle w,v'\rangle}{\langle v',v'\rangle} v'$
>
> $u' = u-\dfrac{\langle u,v'\rangle}{\langle v',v'\rangle} v'-\dfrac{\langle u,w'\rangle}{\langle w',w'\rangle} w'$

Then $u'$ will be perpendicular to both $v$ and $w$ (it is orthogonal to $\mathrm{span}\{v',w'\}=\mathrm{span}\{v,w\}$.

Note that the solution here is *not unique* (in the same way the cross product gives a unique answer: the only vector (1) orthogonal to its inputs (2) length equal to the are of the parallelogram spanned by the inputs and (3) completes a right handed basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$). In general there are many many vectors orthogonal to both $v$ and $w$. The particular $u'$ we find above very much depends on our choice of $u$ (and whether we start Gram-Schmidt with $v$ or $w$ first).

Comment: "orthogonal" in my case means $G(X,Y)=0$.

Comment: I see you mean "metric" to be something like a Riemannian metric. Well, my answer still stands. But instead change the inner products "$\langle v,w \rangle$" with "$G(v,w)$". If you replace "vector" with "vector field", you can get a vector field orthogonal to the input vector *fields* (assuming they don't vanish anywhere).

Comment: I checked on my example how it works. So, obtained vector is orthogonal just on one vector of a basis, but on the other it is not. I am thinking that there is a problem with metric which is not an Euclidean one.

Comment: It should work. Gram-Schmidt works as long as  the bilinear form (in particular for you "metric") is non-degenerate. It doesn't need to be positive definite to work. You should double check you calculation and make use used $w'$ in the final step not $w$.